# Mounting Sparse Bundle on NFS Share

Tags: big-sur, nas, sparsebundle, nfs

**Background**

I have a Seagate BlackArmor NAS220 running Debian. I would like to use the NAS as a target for Time Machine backups from my Mac (2020 Mac mini M1). I have used disk utility to create a 500 GB sparse bundle disk image (HFS+J). I can mount the sparse bundle on my computer no problem when it is stored locally. I then copy the sparse bundle to my NAS.

**Problem**

When I try to mount the sparse bundle on my Mac while it is stored on the NAS (by double-clicking on it) I get the following error:

[image: error1]

When I double click on it again I get this error:

[image: error2]

Attempting to mount via the Terminal using,

`sudo hdiutil attach -verbose /path-to-network-share/MacminiTM.sparsebundle/`

results in,

```
Mac-mini:Time Machine Backups christopher$ sudo hdiutil attach -verbose /path-to-network-share/MacminiTM.sparsebundle/
Initializing…
CBSDBackingStore::newProbe directory, not a valid image file.
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  0, score    -1000, CBSDBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  1, score     1000, CBundleBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  2, score    -1000, CRAMBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  3, score    -1000, CDevBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  4, score    -1000, CCURLBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  5, score    -1000, CVectoredBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  0, score      100, CBSDBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  1, score    -1000, CBundleBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  2, score    -1000, CRAMBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  3, score    -1000, CDevBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  4, score    -1000, CCURLBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  5, score    -1000, CVectoredBackingStore
CBSDBackingStore::newProbe directory, not a valid image file.
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  0, score    -1000, CBSDBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  1, score     1000, CBundleBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  2, score    -1000, CRAMBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  3, score    -1000, CDevBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  4, score    -1000, CCURLBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  5, score    -1000, CVectoredBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  0, score      100, CBSDBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  1, score    -1000, CBundleBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  2, score    -1000, CRAMBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  3, score    -1000, CDevBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  4, score    -1000, CCURLBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  5, score    -1000, CVectoredBackingStore
Attaching…
Error 5 (Input/output error).
Finishing…
DIHLDiskImageAttach() returned 5
hdiutil: attach failed - Input/output error
```

I can't figure out why the sparse bundle mounts fine when it's stored on my Mac locally, but not when on the network share.

Comment: A sparse bundle disk image is a folder. I suppose something happens when copying the folder and its contents. Have you tried a sparse disk image file?

Comment: What @David Anderson said, also if you copy it *back* to the Mac from the NFS share do you get the same error?

Comment: @DavidAnderson this worked for a little bit, but the transfer was super slow and eventually failed saying there was an error copying files.

Comment: @SteveChambers When the sparse bundle is copied back to my computer it mounts normally—no errors.

Comment: cdixon1: I know little about what you are trying to do, but why are you having this problem, when the Seagate BlackArmor NAS220 is suppose to work with Time Machine? See the [NAS Time Machine MAC](https://www.seagate.com/files/support/barracuda/po_blackarmor_nas_time_machine_mac.pdf) link on this [Seagate BlackArmor NAS220](https://www.seagate.com/support/external-hard-drives/network-storage/blackarmor-nas-220/) support page.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I have replaced the stock firmware with a custom Debian image using the following instructions: https://github.com/hn/seagate-blackarmor-nas. For my purposes the NAS220 is a generic Linux server running Debian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by creating an SMB (instead of NFS) share for use with Time Machine backups. That way it was pretty straight forward to copy the sparse bundle and then mount it.